# Is "Recommend/Suggest sb to do sth" Grammarly Correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I learned before that there's two ways to use verbs like recommend/suggest, one is using gerund, and the other is subjunctive mood. (I'm asking about the two words at once due to the similarity of them in both usage and meaning).  For example,

> I recommend/suggest (him) seeing a doctor.

> I recommend/suggest that he see a doctor.

But recently I've heard multiple times from native speakers the usage of "recommend sb to do sth", in this case.

> I recommend him to see a doctor.

I found this rule in *Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English 4th edition*, and I wonder if it just works for "suggest"

[image: longman definition]

So my question is:

1. Is it grammatically correct to say "recommend sb to do sth"?
2. Is it grammatically correct to say "suggest sb to do sth"?

Comment: @ColleenV thanks, I wasn't able to find this one. I also wanna learn about the usage of suggest

Comment: I'm also interested in the case that if the usages between "suggest" and "recommend" are different, say if "recommend sb to do sth" is fine but "suggest sb to do sth" doesn't work, what caused the difference? How should English learners understand this difference instead of simply memorizing?